# what is the zero locus of a morphism of the derived category?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

For a morphism of quasi-coherent sheaves $v\colon E \to F$, on a scheme $X$, one can ask about the locus where $v =0$.

When $F$ is a vector bundle, it's easy to see that this locus is closed.*

> Is there anything we can say for a morphism of complexes in $D(X)$?

(maybe we also want to assume boundedness/perfectness) I don't particularly care if the locus has any natural scheme structure, I would just like to know if there's a chance of it being closed.

(*) Actually more is true. One can play with tensor products and duality and actually deduce that the functor sending a $T \to X$ to the set $\{ f : T \to X : f^*v = 0 \}$ is a closed subscheme of $X$. This is spelled out as Prop 8.4 (2) in Goertz-Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry I. (by the way, I am very much looking forward to Volume II !!!)

Comment: Are you willing to work in $D^b_{\text{coh}}(X)$?  And you want it to be the zero morphism in the derived category I assume (and not just zero on cohomology?)

Comment: @KarlSchwede: Yes, absolutely, out of habit I just wrote $D(X)$ where I meant $D^b(Coh(X))$. As I tend not to work with non-noetherian schemes, this is the same as $D^b_{coh}(X)$.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: Are there morphisms which are zero on cohomology but are not zero? (If not, then we know that the locus is closed if all cohomology groups of $F$ are locally free. Sadly, this is essentially never the case.)

Comment: Yes there are such morphisms.  For instance, I can have a nonzero map between two complexes one of which has cohomology only in degree 1 and the other only which has cohomology in degree 0.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: ah, of course! silly me, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Ok, I'm also slightly confused about what you mean by the locus where $v = 0$.   I assume you don't mean the points where $v$ is the zero morphism on stalks, as then $v$ is zero if and only $v(E) = 0$ and that's obviously an open condition, right?

Comment: uhm, I don't think I mean stalks, as that would imply local rings and so force openness. I like the way Goertz-Wedhorn do it (the functor I mention at the end). Probably another way to say it is that at each geometric point, the derived pullback of that morphism is the zero morphism. A friend suggested to use symmetric algebras. Let's think about this, if $E$ and $F$ are just vector bundles, then geometrically we think of this as being a map $Spec Sym E^\vee \to Spec Sym F^\vee$. Taking the fibre product along the zero section seems related to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Would you mind including in your question a precise definition of what you mean to be *the zero locus of a map between coherent sheaves* or *the zero locus of a map between complexes*?

Comment: For instance, if I have a skyscraper sheaf $F$ supported at a single point and $v : F \to F$ is the identity, what is the zero locus of that map?

Comment: @KarlSchwede: yes, you are obviously right. after I posted my last comment I also thought about skyscrapers. What I'm trying to imitate is the fact that if $v\colon E \to F$ is a map of coherent sheaves such that $F$ is a vector bundle and $v| U = 0$ for an open $U$, then $v = 0$ everywhere. But this is false in the derived category. For example on $P^1$, one has a non-zero morphism $k(p)[-1] \to O(-1)$ which restricted to the complement of $p$ is zero.